# Make Envs Available To Sublime Text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I need to make an environmental variable available to Sublime Text (3).

Specifically, I am using [Ruby Test](https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests) to run RSpec tests on a Rails app. In order for my Rails App to use Postgres it needs access to an env that I'm setting in my `.bash_profile`:

```
# Postgres
export PGHOST=localhost
```

If I launch ST from the Terminal, this env is available because my `.bash_profile`is loaded when I open the shell, however if I open ST by launching the app via its icon or via Alfred, `.bash_profile` is never loaded and this env is not available to ST, causing all my RSpec tests to fail due to problems connecting to the Postgres database.

**So how can I pass environmental variables into Sublime Text (3)?**

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but if you are using the build system, perhaps adding the `"shell": true` option? If it's a plugin you are working through, perhaps create an issue for the plugin (I'm guessing it's on github)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately outside the build system.

Comment: So how are you doing it then?